# Why is Spark not using all cores on local machine

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, mapreduce

When I run some of the Apache Spark examples in the Spark-Shell or as a job, I am not able to achieve full core utilization on a single machine. For example:

```
var textColumn = sc.textFile("/home/someuser/largefile.txt").cache()
var distinctWordCount = textColumn.flatMap(line => line.split('\0'))
                             .map(word => (word, 1))
                             .reduceByKey(_+_)
                             .count()
```

When running this script, I mostly see only 1 or 2 active cores on my 8 core machine.
Isn't Spark supposed to parallelise this?

Comment: Looks you are reading the local file. So there is only one partition, and `flatMap` and `map` only use one core. You can use `numPartitions` parameter in `reduceByKey` to set the parallelism. E.g., `reduceByKey(_+_, 8)`. Then `reduceByKey` and `count` will use 8 cores.

Comment: @zsxwing Where are you seeing them specifying only one partition? the .cache doesn't limit partitions does it?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `local[*]` to run Spark locally with as many worker threads as logical cores has your machine.

Comment: Meaning set the configuration parameter `"spark.master"` to `"local[*]"`.

Answer (score 2):

when you run a local spark shell, you still have to specify the number of cores that your spark tasks will use.  if you want to use 8 cores make sure you

```
export MASTER=local[8]
```

before running your shell.

Also, as @zsxwing says, you may need to ensure that your data is partitioned into enough partitions to keep all of the cores busy, or that you specify the amount of parallelism you want to see.

Comment: `export` is convenient on Linux-like machine. How to do it on Windows?

Comment: you can set it as one of your spark configuration properties in your code.  To make it more flexible, pass it in as a command parameter

Comment: or on the command line where you call spark-shell: [`./bin/spark-shell --master spark://IP:PORT`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#connecting-an-application-to-the-cluster)