# I just want to give a dataset which have billions of data a sorted row number tag,what to do in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have billions of data in hdfs, now I want to load the data by Spark and then give every record a sorted number tag, how cloud I write the code so that I can get the most efficient performance?

Let's consider for example, this dataset:

```
100.0
120.0
400.0
500.0
20.0
12.0
33.0
...
8.0
9.0
...
```

The result I just want to get is:

```
0.0 1
1.0 2
5.0 3
8.0 4
9.0 5
...
27898880 2500000
27898893 2500001
....
```

I have tried the window function row_number() in SparkSQL as below, but it can not use the multi-cores, it just run in single-core, so it is so slow.

```
select
    score,
    row_number() over(order by score) as sort
from
    my_score_data
```

Comment: Check out this previous posts, which has some links about Spark and multi-core: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716949/can-spark-use-multicore-properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention it, a non partioned window is not a good idea. Indeed, not only is it mono core, but it also creates a lot of shuffle. All the data ends up in one partition, and thus on one node, which can cause an out of memory error (and most certainly will with large datasets).

To solve your problem, there are several solutions in Spark. The simplest one is to use the RDD API. If you need consecutive indices, you can use `zipWithIndex`. It is much more efficient than a window. It triggers a simple spark job.

```scala
val rdd = sc
    .textFile("hdfs:///pathToFile/file.txt")
    .sortBy(identity) // just in case you want sorted data
val tupleRDD = rdd.zipWithIndex // A rdd of tuple, the index is at the 2nd place
val stringRDD = tupleRDD.map(t => t._1 + " " + t._2) // we can also create a string
```

If you don't need consecutive indices, but only increasing indices (with possible gaps), you can use `zipWithUniqueId()` instead. It does not trigger any spark job and will thus be extremely efficient.

Comment: OK, thanks. I not only want to get the indices of the records but also hope the indices can label the order of the records according to the value of records. The zipWithUniqueId or zipWithIndex functions seem just consturct the indexes of the record but can not label the order of records.

Comment: And when I execute  the window SQL above in SparkSQL, I set the config "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1000" in the Spark-submit commands, but it seems not come into effect and just run in single-core.

Comment: Right, this I why I suggested not to use a Window in that case. Also I am not sure to understand what you mean by "label the order of records". Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sorry, my words is not clear.In fact, I want the massive dataset to be global sorted and then get the ordered index of every record, this is just my orginal requirement.

Comment: Oh right. You can sort the data first then. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Comment: Really thanks.But my reputation is less than 15 in this system because  I am a new one, my vote would not be displayed.So sorry for that.

Comment: No problem, but even if you cannot vote, you can accept the answer. It's the grey button that looks like a "V" below the voting buttons ;-)

Comment: And another question, you said `a non partioned window is not a good idea` above, so is there a way to get multi-partitions when use window function?

Comment: Yes, you simply need to use "partition by" with the column(s) you want to use. Each distinct value will correspond to a partition.